# Executing jQuery code after images are loaded in an Ajax called page

Tags: jquery

I know that using $(window).load() the code executes after everything's loaded. But it doesn't seem to work when load() is called from a page loaded through Ajax.

That is: a click on a certain link in my page loads a page via Ajax, and it is in that page that I want to display images and execute jQuery code after they're loaded.

How to do that ?

Comment: Define "loads a page via ajax". If you are actually using ajax, then on your success handler the page would be "loaded".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery the ready handler is used to execute after the dom is ready. Here is the link to the jQuery api: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2):

[`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) has callback function in whitch you can execute code and display images:

```
$('#container').load('myurl.html', function() {
  $('#myimg').show(); // show images here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the ajax Success / error event.

Huw does your ajax call look like ?

Answer (score 0):

call that scripts in callback function:

```
$("#id").load("", function(){
    /in here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something in the following logic

```
 var imgCount = $('parent img').length,
        imgLoaded = 0,
        $('parent img').load(function() {
            imgLoaded++;
            if (imgLoaded == imgCount) {
             //images are loaded
            }
        });
```